# how to add elements to a collection

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

Im new to underscore and trying to achieve the below:I have a look up collection and result collection:

```
 $scope.Countries:[{Country:UK,City:London,Areacode:567},
{Country:USA,City:Texas,Areacode:987},
{Country:CHINA,City:XXX,Areacode:XXX}]

$scope.People= [{Fname:'John',Country:'USA'},{Fname:'Bob',Country:'UK'},];
```

I want a single collection which will add the country fields to people collection based on their mapped country as below:

```
    $scope.Result=[{Fname:'John',Country:'USA',City:Texas,Areacode:987}
,{Fname:'Bob',Country:'UK',City:London,Areacode:567}];
```

Can someone throw some light on how to achieve this using underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) across the people collection and [extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) each person with the appropriate country:

```
    var countries = [
        {Country:'UK',  City:'London', Areacode:567},
        {Country:'USA', City:'Texas',  Areacode:987}
    ];

    var people = [
        {Fname:'John', Country:'USA'},
        {Fname:'Bob',  Country:'UK'},
        {Fname:'Jane', Country:'UK'},
        {Fname:'Dai',  Country:'WALES'}
    ];

    var result = _.map(people, function(person){
        var country = _.findWhere(countries, { Country: person.Country });
        return _.extend(person, country);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,i achieved the same using below `code` var some_map = _.map($scope.People, function(item) {
   var child=_.where($scope.Countries,{Country:item.Country});
   item.City=child[0].City;
   item.AreaCode=child[0].Areacode;
   return item;
});  but ur code is much simpler and neat...

Answer (score 0):

use filter:

```
$scope.result = _.filter($scope.people, function(person) {
    person.country === 'USA'; // or some other value
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,filter will result the matching row from the collection but Im not looking for that.I want to know how to combine both the collections in a simple way instead of using for loop and creating a new collection...